# how can I made apache ranger with hdfs plugin logging superuser in superusergroups

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, audit, apache-ranger

I've installed apache ranger 2.4.0 and hdfs plugin on hadoop hdfs namenode (standalone, not HA)

dfs.permissions.superusergroup property's value is [myhero]. it's set hdfs-site.xml

and my ranger-admin is not logging hdfs access via myhero account

how can I do logging myhero's access history that?